# How to install stacktrace library to my existing boost?

Tags: boost, stack-trace, backtrace

Stacktrace is in Version 1.65.0, but I have boost 1.53.0 on my linux machine.

I need to install it into my existing boost.
Note: Stacktrace has no dependencies.

How to add entries in jam file so that when I build the boost with Stacktrace folder, it should build stacktrace as well?

Comment: It does depend on other boost libraries, just look through the code. I see `array`, `lexical_cast`, `type_traits`, `config`, `static_assert`, `detail`... and most importantly [`core`](https://github.com/boostorg/core), which first appeared in 1.56